# Open a Modal with ReactNative does not work

Tags: javascript

I want that when I click on my button "More", the last tab of my list, it opens a Modal but with my code it does not work. How to make it work ?

```
function MyTabs() {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(true);
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Mon compte" component={AccountScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Mes transferts" component={TransfertsScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Créer" component={CreerScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Suivi" component={SuiviScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="More" component={MoreScreen} listeners={({ navigation, route }) => ({
                tabPress: e => {
                    console.log(1)
                    e.preventDefault();
                    <Modal isVisible={modal}>
                      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                        <Text>I am the modal content!</Text>
                        <Button title="Fermer la modale" onPress={() => {setModal(false);}}></Button>
                      </View>
                    </Modal>
                },
            })} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<Button title="Fermer la modale" onPress={() => setModal(false)}></Button>
```